# Deface _products data-hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I want to add taxonomies from sidebar to main page, instead of list of products, but my deface is not working.

```
Deface::Override.new(
:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_products',
:name => 'change view',
:replace => "[data-hook='homepage_products']",
:text => "
            <% max_level = Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1 %>
            <nav id='taxonomies2' class='sidebar-item' data-hook>
                <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
                    <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level] do %>
                        <h4 class='taxonomy-root'><%= Spree.t(:shop_by_taxonomy, :taxonomy => taxonomy.name) %></h4>
                        <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, max_level) %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </nav> ")
```

I am stuck at this really badly.

Comment: You don't need to mention data-hook in the nav id tag , Instead mention it in the actual view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the virtual path with the homepage index view one: `spree/home/index`, where the element you are trying to replace is placed.

Also, I'm not sure name should contain a space, try changing it with "change_view". Always be sure the name is unique and restart your server when adding a new deface override file.

Comment: If you are in development environment, no need to restart when adding a new deface override file.

Answer (score 1):

**Case - Restarting Server**: No need to restart the server every time you make changes in overrides.

Yes, You should if you have set `config.deface.enabled = false`; normally we set this in `production.rb` and in that case you should precompile the overrides. [See this for more info](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/rails-spree-in-production-deface-stuffs/)

---

**Debugging technique**:
If you are not sure the path for the partial/template is correct then you can verify using this technique

```
$ rake deface:get_result['spree/shared/_link_to_account']
=> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template

$ rake deface:get_result['spree/shared/_login_bar']
# ---------------- Before ----------------
# <% if spree_current_user %>
#   <li><%= link_to Spree.t(:my_account), spree.account_path %></li>
#   <li><%= link_to Spree.t(:logout), spree.logout_path %></li>
# <% else %>
```

You can even verify the selectors, like

```
$ rake deface:test_selector['spree/shared/_login_bar , li']
# Querying 'spree/shared/_login_bar' for 'li'
# ---------------- Match 1 ----------------
# <li>
# <%= link_to 'Dashboard', '/admin' if spree_current_user.is_admin? %> </li>
# ---------------- Match 2 ----------------
```

Moreover, if the error persists even after the selector has been verified, then you have to make sure the `text` you are going to replace with does not contain any `syntax`/`runtime` error.